# SharePoint 2010 Designer Workflow - Last Published Date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How can I see the last published date for a SharePoint Designer workflow? I can only see the last modified date, along with the a version history of each time the workflow was saved.

But I can't seem to find any information regarding when was the workflow las published. Is this information available somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the Modified Date and Modified By information in SharePoint Designer by going to All Files - Workflows - Workflow Name. This is the closest you can get. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Workflow All Files]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However, I would like to retrieve the last published date, not the modified date. Makes sense?